# Why some of the value in inverse matrix become positive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations

[image]
[image]

Ans:

[image]
[image]

But why? Isn't it calculate something like this:
[image]
Please help explain.
Thank you!

Comment: No the matrix part of the inverse is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 \\
-2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: See this explanation, it's very clear and thorough: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html

Comment: @Brian Hey, that's very clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link: [Inverse of a Matrix](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html)

The formula is:
[image]

Comment: Then follow this link: http://bancomicsans.com/main/  ;-)